# facebook login Server-side Apps with javascript sdk

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-login

I have searched stackoverflow for an full example or some blog that explains how to make facebook login Server-side Apps with javascript sdk
but didn't find anything.

I have searched developer.facebook.com site and the only thing i have got was a php example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/.
The problem is that i must use JavaScript.

Why should i want to do that?
The reason is that i want to upload files to the server(google-app-engine(Java Sdk)) and save  them on the db with the facebook user id and retrieve them by his user id.

another question is, how can i debug my javascript code if he uploaded dynamically?what about code assist?

Comment: The js sdk comes with a full working example, did you give that a shot? I was in the same boat a few months ago---if you are using php, try the php example first, then slide in the js example. You still have to work out the server side logic first, from my understanding.

Comment: I am not familiar with php at all thats why i dont know what are they doing there.
Can you give your code? how to do server side connection by javascript sdk?

Comment: Gimme a few hours...will post as answer soon...

Comment: Ok- I have it up. You can go to the working example at the bottom. The php is there for the settings. What do you want to do with the information? I'll make changes accordingly.

Comment: Oh- didn't realize you were seeking a java solution--- palm to forehead...

Answer (score 1):

Well I can help you with this issue. If you need to use the JS SDK of FB, then you have to do everything on the client side or on browser, because Facebook doesn't have any support for Java on Server Side.

So I suggest you that you can authenticate user on client, define your scopes for accessing user profile, once authenticated by user you will get response as JSON Object which you can send using ajax to AppEngine Backend.

I am sharing my link where I used FB Login and accessing User's Profile Information along with his photos in albums and videos.

http://demositeunicfyp.appspot.com/fb-pictures.html

http://demositeunicfyp.appspot.com/facebook.html

You can Debug the JS Code in your browser to see what kind of response object you are getting back from Facebook APIs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Initializing the Facebook SDK
        FB.init({
            appId : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            status : true,
            cookie : true,
            xfbml : true,
            oauth : true
        });

        // Method to check if a user is looged in to FB or Not
        FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);

        $("#logout").live("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                $("#loginDiv").show();
                $("#logoutDiv").hide();
            });
        });


        $("#fbLoginButton").live("click", function(event) {
            //event.preventDefault();
            FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
        });

        function updateButton(response) {
            var button = document.getElementById("fbLoginButton");

            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user is already logged in and connected
                // button.innerHTML = 'Facebook Logout';
                //$("#loginDiv").hide();
                //$("#logoutDiv").show();
                //window.location = '/confirm';

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    $("#userName").text(response.name);
                    $("#userEmail").text(response.email);
                });

            } else {
                // user is not connected to your app or logged out
                // button.innerHTML = 'Facebook Login';

                button.onclick = function() {
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            // button.innerHTML = 'Facebook Logout';
                            $("#loginDiv").hide();
                            $("#logoutDiv").show();

                            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                                $("#userName").text(response.name);
                                $("#userEmail").text(response.email);
                            });
                        } else {
                            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization hence do nothing
                        }
                    }, {
                        scope : 'email,publish_actions'
                    });
                }
            }
        }
   });
```

Comment: Ankur Jain, do you have to deploy it to app enginge server each time you are making changes\like to add more code to your project, or you can make it work on you local pc?
from what i have seen you must tell facebook your website url in order to work on.

Comment: Well I have one app key for my local host and I create the one for whatever url/website I need key so I just replace the Key when deploying to appengine server.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from JS.php in SDK download

```
  <?php

require '../folderTo/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
  $user_profile = $facebook->api('me?fields=photos');  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
      Your user profile is
      <pre>
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Working example here:  http://slicethegreen.com/examples/js.php